# Some pictures of a slider does not show in Chrome, but do in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider and set in different pages because it is an artist work, but some pictures do not show in chrome, but in firefox and internet explorer it works fine!

Comment: Hey. Welcome to StackOverflow. It'd be nice if you could explain your problem a bit better, and include a [mcve] _in the question itself_. If you have any issues, please read [ask].

Comment: It looks fine on both browsers